# Cannot run Vue.js application because of the error

Tags: vue.js

I'm doing a project that requires me to use MongoDB, Express and Vue.js.
I have set up the mongo and it's working. However, I'm having issues with Vue.js.
How can I solve the issue? Nothing works when I run `npm run start`
[image]

Comment: you can not run `app.vue` file. because it is not a process

Answer (score 0):

That is not issue with **Vue**, there is already command to start project, use **npm run serve** instead.

For the future, read more about **NPM** and **Vue CLI**

Answer (score 0):

You need to check OFFICIAL documentation NPM from here https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script

You have not a VUE error.

Answer (score 0):

use `npm run serve` to start a dev server

and `npm run build` to build for deployment.

follow this guide to learn more about vue-cli
[Vue Cli Guide Page](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/)